# How to get respective dynamically created element values on button click

Tags: javascript

I have created a card structure based on results array fetched from API as:

`results` holds the list of fetched data
`resultsDiv` is an empty div to append all cards in it

created cards as :

```
results.forEach((pred, idx) => {
            const card = document.createElement('div')
            card.classList.add('card');
            card.id = idx;
            const image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = pred["image_path"]
            image.classList.add('image-style')
            card.append(image)
            const info = document.createElement('h4')
            info.innerText = 'Tenant ID: ' + pred["tenant_id"]
            card.append(info)
            resultsDiv.append(card)
            const ol = document.createElement('ol')
            pred['prediction'].forEach(p => {
                const li = document.createElement('li')
                const checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
                checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                li.innerText = p
                li.appendChild(checkbox)
                ol.appendChild(li)
            })
            card.append(ol)
            const btn = document.createElement('button')
            btn.innerText = 'Verify'
            btn.classList.add('verify-btn')
            const textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
            textarea.placeholder = 'comments...'
            card.append(btn)
            card.append(textarea)
        })
```

[image: It shows up as :]

Now I want to get all the data that are selected on respective card on clicking its own button (each button i have added an event listener)

currently I am getting the values using `closest` this works but i think its not the appropriate way :

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const cardDiv = btn.closest('div');
        const allElems = cardDiv.childNodes;
        const imagePath = allElems[0].src;  // image src
        const comments = allElems[4].value; // 
       
     })
```

May I know any efficient way of getting the values as above , any guiding links or a solution would be much helpful

TIA

Comment: That's absolutely an appropriate way of doing this. You should use classes though: `const cardDiv = btn.closest('.card');` and `const imagePath = cardDiv.querySelector('.image-style').src` etc so you don't have to hard-code child indexes.

Comment: Add a class to the checkboxes (a different class for each card) and then use `getElementsByClassname` to get all checkboxes with the same class. Then you can check if those are checked or not.

Comment: @ChrisG makes sense :) .... Thanks bud

Comment: @Geshode ahh nice ... cool way to get them too ...

Comment: Don't use different classes (unfeasible and unnecessary), just use `cardDiv.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')` or similar.

Comment: much cleaner ... thanks again @ChrisG ,hope I'm not out if context of Q , i have one more query , for say if i had a radio instead of checkbox how would i make only one radio selected out of 3 as in above picture

Comment: Give them all the same `name` attribute (unique for each card) and give one of them `checked="checked"`

Comment: @ChrisG , my bad i tried and it worked as charm ... here is the same `name` attribute is the reason to allow single button to check ?

Comment: It's how radio buttons work; you give them the same `name` to group them. The value of `name` is used as the key when form data is sent to the server.

Comment: @ChrisG easy to miss out fundamentals ... my bad how silly !! :(

Comment: Don't worry, people usually start with JavaScript when learning PHP first would save them tons of time and frustration :)